# How to see if (for example) array[3] exists

Tags: c#, string

I want to type some strings in the console. for example "hello im 20", and I want to split the line into little strings. With those strings I want to do something. But when you put in "hello  im", it should be possible to write a line like: "forgot to put in your ago"So I tried (words[2] == null), but this doens't work.

```
string line
line = Console.ReadLine();

                    string[] words = new string[3];
                    words = line.Split(' ');
                    foreach(string word in words)
                    {
                         if (words[2] == null)
                         {
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             int a = Int32.Parse(words[2]);
                                    //do something here with a
                         }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item in an array at position `3` is actually the fourth item, since we start counting at `0` (as we say, arrays are 0-based).

So you have to check if the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) is at least 4 (`0`, `1`, `2` and `3`).

Since the length is an integer, and integers can't contain fractions (you can't have half an item in the array), it is safe to check if the count is more than three:

```
if (words.Length > 3)
{ }
```

A side note: Your variable assignment makes no sense. In fact, you set the array twice. Just assign the variable at once:

```
string[] words = line.Split(' ');
```

Comment: You are welcome. And next time, to choose such a cheap user name ;)

Comment: Haha :P Thank you very much, im fine now

Answer (score 1):

Why not do -

```
string[] words = line.Split(' ');
if (words.Length == 2) 
{ //do stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find whether the length of array is greater than 2. If it is then you can check for its value